# Unexpected behavior: Node.js vs Vanila JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code:

```js
var fullname = "John Doe";
var obj = {
  fullname: "Colin Ihrig",
  prop: {
    fullname: "Aurelio De Rosa",
    getFullname: function () {
      return this.fullname;
    },
  },

  getFirstName: () => {
    console.log(this);
    return this.fullname.split(" ")[0];
  },
};

console.log(obj.prop.getFullname());
console.log(obj.getFirstName());
```

When I run the above code in browser. `this` inside the `getFirstName()` points to the `window` object (which is expected). When I run the same code in `Node.js` shell it gives the same output (intead of `window`, `this` now points to the `global` object).

However, when I run code as `node prog.js`:

The code throws the following error:

```bash
Aurelio De Rosa
{}
/home/x/code/var.js:13
    return this.fullname.split(" ")[0];
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at Object.getFirstName (/home/x/code/revise/ctci/var.js:13:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/x/code/revise/ctci/var.js:18:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.14.1
```

Here is the [demo](https://replit.com/@methecode/SeparateEcstaticIntercept#index.js).

Why is that?